# fatal exception:main,Runtime exception unable to start activity

Tags: android-fragments

I want to know what went wrong in this which object is showing as null pointer here. Please do clarify me.

Here is my code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    int mFlipping = 0 ; // Initially flipping is off
    Button mButton ;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.flipper1);

                if (mFlipping == 0) {
                    /** Start Flipping */
                    flipper.startFlipping();
                    mFlipping = 1;
                    mButton.setText(R.string.str_btn_stop);
                } else {
                    /** Stop Flipping */
                    flipper.stopFlipping();
                    mFlipping = 0;
                    mButton.setText(R.string.str_btn_start);
                }
            }
        };

        /** Getting a reference to the button available in the resource */
        mButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn);

        /** Setting click event listner for the button */
        mButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    return rootView;
}
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error output you get, this will tell you the line number. If you use a debugger you will see which variable is null. Have you done this?

Comment: I think in the menu Inflater i have forgotten  to add string reference for the frames that is it is showing frames are not available....could you please tell me how to include frames inside that menu inflater..?

Comment: animationSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Animation animationSlideInLeft, android.R.anim.slide_in_left); error showing ' , ' or ) is expected please help